# Views hierarchical taxonomy select box

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views, drupal-taxonomy

I'm trying to create a Drupal web for a travel agency and need your help.

- I store locations in a taxonomy with hierarchy, the structure looks like this:

  - Europe

    - France

      - Paris
    - Germany

      - Berlin
- I'm using a view with "Has taxonomy terms (with depth)" filter, exposed as a selectbox.
- "Show hierarchy in dropdown" is enabled

It works fine, but the selectbox starts to get pretty huge as the number of the location is increasing.

So my question is:
Is it possible to show just the 1st and 2nd level of the taxonomy in the select box?
Or is it possible to show each level of the taxonomy in a separate select box?

Thank you!

Comment: You don't mention which version of drupal, which makes a big difference. I had to do this in Drupal 7 recently and had to create my own module which supplied a block and used the form api to create the 3 separate hierarchical select boxes. The first 2 had the #ajax set so they would update the form and populate the next select.

Comment: I use Drupal 7. I'm sure that custom module could solve this problem, but I'm trying to find some simple solution.

Comment: "Is it possible to show just the 1st and 2nd level of the taxonomy in the select box?" It is possible but I have never seen a module to do this. It could be done in a simple HOOK_form_alter.
"Is it possible to show each level of the taxonomy in a separate select box?" The only module I have seen for this is Hierarchical Select. http://drupal.org/project/hierarchical_select. I have never used it though. I needed to implement this a few weeks back and implemented my own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use hierarchical select module to create select list. This will give you a hierarchy with '-' symbol in front all child elements.
Then you can alter the form with hook_form_alter function.

```
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
 if (($form_id == 'your_form_id')) {
  foreach ($form['tid']['#options'] as $term_key => $term) {
      // Check if this is a child by looking for '-' as first char in string
      $term_value = reset($term->option);
      if($term_value[0] == '-') {
        unset($form['tid']['#options'][$term_key]);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check [this link](http://drupal.org/node/463678). I am pretty sure, you will be able to it by some custom coding in any custom module or template.php

You can check [this module too](http://drupal.org/project/reference_option_limit), really helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

"is it possible to show each level of the taxonomy in a separate select box?"
The only module I have seen that might be useful to you is the Hierarchical Select module. http://drupal.org/project/hierarchical_select